# Vitejs: WebSocket connection to 'wss://host:port/' failed due to HMR

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, webpack-hmr

I deployed a Vue page with Docker and Kubernetes and it is working. However, even though I disabled HMR, Vite keeps refreshing after an error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://dashboard.default.io:8181/' failed:
>
> [vite] server connection lost. polling for restart...

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 8181
CMD [ "yarn", "dev","--host", "--port", "8181" ]
```

`yarn dev` calls `vite` command

vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    hmr: false
  }
})
```

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: 'https://backend.default.io'
    }
  }
```

package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "yarn": "^1.22.18"
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.6.0",
    "vite": "^2.5.1",
}
```

I could not figure out why it is still using HMR since I disabled it. And, how can I fix this? I also tried `server.hmr.clientPort: 443` but it also did not work.

It would be sufficient to just disable hmr.

Comment: have u resolve this problem ? i got the same issue and looking for solutions

Comment: I used nginx to render, it resolves the issue.

Comment: me too I used nginx, and configure it with this tutorial https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue in a Laravel Inertia-Vue js app in production. I solved it by adding the following server configurations to vite.config.js.

```
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
   ...
],
server: {
    port: 3000,
    https: true,
    hmr: {
        host: "yourdomainname.com",
        port: 3001,
        protocol: "wss",
    },
},
```

});

For more information, refer to this link: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/1926

**update**
If it refreshes when it is in production, go to the `public` folder and find a file named `.hot`.
Delete that file and everything would work well.

Comment: Didn't work for me on local environment. `WebSocket server error:
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:433
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1723:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1937:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:8)`

Answer (score 0):

I set `server.hmr.clientPort` same as `server.port`. I works for me.

My vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    host: true,
    strictPort: true,
    port: 5173,
    hmr: {
      clientPort: 5173,
    },
  }
})
```